# Banner with navigation links, should it be NAV or DIV?

Tags: html, accessibility, nav, role

I have a banner on top of some pages, HTML5. It is for navigation and also includes some search fields (another kind of navigation).

Should I use `<nav role="banner">` or `<div role="banner">`?

Inside the banner there is a list with two links. Should I place those in a new `<nav>`?

Should I place the search fields in another small `<nav>`?

Comment: So you have two navigation lists? One "for navigation" and another "list with two links"? Or what is the purpose of the second list?

Comment: Good question, @unor. Perhaps I will try to enhance my question above a bit. The whole banner is for navigation. Maybe just the banner should be <nav> and there should be no <nav> inside it?